# Acceptable memory limits on a VOIP, MySQL and HTTP server

Tags: linux, memory

I'm currently running a Mandriva(Linux) server with fairly low memory (1GB). At the moment the specs are looking like this(it currently is used for VoIP(sip), MySQL and HTTP):

```
freememory total freeswap totalswap buffers cached
30         997   840      1003      7       286
```

When i look at free memory, it does disturb me that its running so low, (30MB!), but the cached is looking ok (286MB, or 25%). I'm used to running Windows in which the cached memory automatically gets released when needed. Would the server be doing this? **Is this how Linux memory management works?**

Is that enough spare memory in general? **Should I endeavor to minimize memory usage?**

And the last one, whats the best tool to read memory usage per process? When i look at *top*, the top usage is 4.2 mem, second one is 0.9, the third was 0.0. **So where is it all being used?**

I know 1GB isn't a lot, but these servers are from like 2003, and there is no budget for an upgrade
Thanks

Comment: Consider [my answer here](http://serverfault.com/a/379392/9770) and see if that answers your question.