# Linux server memory allocation

Tags: linux, memory

I have a linux server with tomcat and MySql installed on it, with axis2 as well.

At first I started with ~400MB allocated
I deployed my project and still memory allocation was the same.

But then I tried to use Log4j, which I think caused the problem.
Problem is that not I have ~800MB allocated.
Then I removed the service I deployed and still 800MB allocated.

What have I done wrong? How can I check what have done wrong and fix it?

Thanks
Yoav

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/379392/115189

Comment: Have a look at http://serverfault.com/questions/377617 for interpreting the top output. If your tomcat + mysql memory is still elevated, then you may have a problem. Otherwise, it sounds like you're running into the trap of thinking the "Free" line is "my programs are using everything but this", which is not true in Linux.

Answer (score 1):

This is the linux caching mechanism and is totally normal and nothing to worry about. Linux will free memory if another application requests memory.

You can enforce that all not-needed memory is freed (`sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`), however this is not necessary and linux will work perfectly fine even if 98% memory shows up as used